# How to retrive the session value and view the logged user's email in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am using `C#` in `ASP.NET` accourding to `mvc` and trying to make login as here. In my `Login.cshtml` file the logging form is submitting to `LoginFirst()` method in AccountController.cs controller. Here i need to store the email in session and i need to retrive it in my `_LoginPartial.cshtml` file to view it as "Hello " But i don't know how to retrieve it. (Here my CustomerProID is the email)

**AccountController.cs**

[image]

And here i need to show "Hello " on top of the home page after Login. So for that my `_LoginPartial.cshtml` is as follows.

[image]

In the above attachemnt i have changed the condition which is inside the if clause from `Request`.IsAuthentication to `Session["LoggedIn"]==true` That's why here i wanted to use sessions instead of the inbuilt things for login purposes. But now the problem is i don't know how to change `User.Identity.GetUsername()` thing which inside the ActionLink. I'm a fresher to this environment and need help to solve this.

Comment: You have  a user name in CustomerPro ?

Comment: When the time that user is registering it is considering email, password and confirm password only. But in my CustomerPro.cs model class has Fname, Lname and other attributes for customer profile. So when user is registering all those values are passing as null except email,password and confirm password.